# Python packages not available after install with pip

Tags: python, package, pip

I am working on a Macbook with Python 2.7.5 pre-installed. I installed the pandas package via command-line with the following code.

```
pip install pandas
```

This completed without errors. However, when I try to run the following code in Netbeans, I get an error.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
import pandas as pd
```

The error is: *ImportError: No module named pandas*

When I try to re-install the pandas package in the terminal I get the message: *Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pandas in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages*

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you have two python installs, what does `which -a python` output? If you start an interpreter with `/usr/local/bin/python` can you import pandas?

Comment: This gives as result: /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python

Comment: `/usr/bin/python` is the system default, you can remove `/usr/local/bin/python` or just specify that you want to use that interpreter in netbeans, pip is installing packages for the `/usr/local/bin/python` interpreter not the system python