# Python not finding installed packages through pip on Linux

Tags: python, linux, numpy, installation, pip

I've been trying to install some new python packages with pip, but for some reason, python is not finding them after installation. This started when I purged my whole install of python, and reinstalled it using apt-get. I installed:

```
python
python2.7
python2.7-dev
python-setuptools
```

When I run:

```
sudo pip list
```

I get:

```
decorator (3.4.0)
flann (1.8.4)
ipython (3.2.0)
itsdangerous (0.24)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
numpy (1.9.2)
pexpect (3.1)
pip (7.1.0)
setuptools (18.0.1)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
Werkzeug (0.10.4)
```

so numpy is listed as installed. In addition, a

```
locate numpy
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/dh_numpy
/usr/include/numpy
/usr/include/python2.7/numpy
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external/decorators/_numpy_testing_noseclasses.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external/decorators/_numpy_testing_noseclasses.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external/decorators/_numpy_testing_utils.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/external/decorators/_numpy_testing_utils.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.9.2.egg-info
/usr/share/numpy
/usr/share/doc/python-numpy
/usr/share/man/man1/dh_numpy.1.gz
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-numpy.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-numpy.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-numpy.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-numpy.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-numpy.prerm
```

so it seems like the installation is alright. But if I try to import it from python, I get an import error. I've tried many things, like purging the entire python installation, purging pip, easy_install and reinstalling all that, massing with the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME variables, and so forth. For reference, echoing the variables PYTHONPATH returns empty and PYTHONHOME returns:

```
/usr
```

In addition, the sys.path variable contains:

```
['',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

So it is looking in both the /usr/lib/python2.7 directories and in /usr/local/lib/python2.7. Given this question:

[Python packages not available after install with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27628814/python-packages-not-available-after-install-with-pip)

I suspect this has something to do with the installation of python that pip is serving. But I only have python in /usr/bin, and not in /usr/local/bin, so I have no idea why pip is installing in local. Plus, as the sys.path variable shows, python should be looking into /usar/local/python2.7 as well. Other packages such as flask, bitarray, and redis have this problem as well. Thank you for the help!

**EDIT:**

Another important information to add: `which -a python` outputs `/usr/bin/python`, so the python being used is in /usr/bin.

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: I forgot to add this. It outputs /usr/bin/python

Comment: Did you ever install another python?

Comment: Not that I recall of, but I might have mistakenly installed another version when trying to install some package. Is there any way to check for leftovers of other python versions? My /usr/local/bin do not have any python installed.

Comment: It did at one time or another and you removed the binary I imagine. Simplest fix is to remove the current version of pip, download get-pip.py and `sudo python get-pip.py` https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. I would also probably  remove the packages directories related to your old install

Answer (score 1):

if you had previously another python installation, I suspect pip is still associated with the old version.
type `$ pip -V` if it's not 2.7 create a symlink for /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip2.7 to usr/bin/pip
I see that the packages are installed in the right place so maybe you can try `$ python -V` as well
ps:
This should go as a comment but I don't have enough "reputations" to add a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is what is happening. A sudo pip -V returns: 
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

I tried a symlink like you suggested, but it did not work. There is no path Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip2.7.

Comment: what does {$ sudo python -V} returns ?